# Paypal Pro: Merchant Country not supported errror

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro

Suddenly from past few days, I am receiving this error when I am trying to do checkout with my credit card. I am using Paypal Payment Pro in magento.

"PayPal gateway has rejected request. The merchant country is not supported (#10565: Merchant country unsupported)."
Below is the log for the transaction Which I have processed.

```
2019-09-19T18:56:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    [DoDirectPayment] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
            [IPADDRESS] => 103.83.147.197
            [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
            [AMT] => 0.50
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
            [INVNUM] => 100005331
            [NOTIFYURL] => https://jworldstore.com/index.php/paypal/ipn/
            [EMAIL] => steve****03@gmail.com
            [CREDITCARDTYPE] => ****
            [ACCT] => ****
            [EXPDATE] => ****
            [CVV2] => ****
            [ISSUENUMBER] => 
            [ITEMAMT] => 0.50
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [L_NUMBER0] => 38137435769
            [L_NAME0] => Testing only Product
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 0.50
            [BUSINESS] => 
            [FIRSTNAME] => steve
            [LASTNAME] => choi
            [MIDDLENAME] => 
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            [STATE] => NY
            [CITY] => flushing 
            [STREET] => **** **** street
            [ZIP] => 11354
            [PHONENUM] => *********
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => NY
            [SHIPTOCITY] => flushing 
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => **** *** street
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 11354
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => **********
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
            [STREET2] => 
            [SHIPTONAME] => steve choi
            [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2019-09-19T18:56:20Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 5b626bd47aa23
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 53530896
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10565
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Merchant country unsupported.
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The merchant country is not supported.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
            [AMT] => 0.50
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        )

    [__pid] => 19820
)
```

As I have checked I found that this error is due to Paypal pro is only available in US And Canada. But as you can see the paypal log. My country is US. Also my Paypal business account is of US. Still I am getting this error. I have contacted Paypal support they said their is no issue from Paypal side. My magento version is 1.9.3.0

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can anyone please help me?